# Backbone model attributes raising TypeError when being called

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am trying to access items of an array in a model and it's raising errors but seems to be finding the correct attribute and writing it to the console still

```
class GD.Views.Place extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['mobile/templates/place']
  initialize: ->
    @model.on('change', @render, this)
  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(place:@model, open:@openNow() ))
    console.log @model.get("coordinates")
    console.log @model.get("coordinates")[0]
    console.log @model.get("coordinates")[1]
    console.log("done")
    this
  openNow: ->
    ...
```

The view is not rendering on-screen and I am seeing this message in my console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
  GD.Views.Place.Place.render
  GD.Routers.Main.Main.place
  _.extend.route
  (anonymous function)
  _.some._.any
  _.extend.loadUrl
  _.extend.start
  window.GD.init
  (anonymous function)
  jQuery.Callbacks.fire
  jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith
  jQuery.extend.ready
  DOMContentLoaded
[51.4528837, -0.9739059999999428]
51.4528837
-0.9739059999999428
done
```

The error message is referring to the 2nd and 3rd console.log lines above. It also seems to be raising errors when accessing further attributes in embedded hashes.

I don't understand why this is happening or how to work around it. Thanks for the help/patience in advance!

Comment: What does `@model.get("coordinates")` return ?

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but shouldn't you be passing @model.toJSON() to the template?

Comment: @asawyer: it returns [51.4528837, -0.9739059999999428], as in the console output above

Comment: @Sandro: the model data in my template has been working for everything else I've been playing around with apart from hashes and arrays so I think mu is too short is on the right track

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual pattern with a Backbone view is this:

```
v = new V
$(something).append(v.render().el)
```

If you combine that with a common pattern for initializing a model:

```
m = new M
m.fetch() # asynchronous!
```

then you can get this:

```
m = new M
m.fetch()
v = new V(model: m)
$(something).append(v.render().el)
```

That would allow the `v.render()` inside the `append` call to happen *before* the model has been fetched from the server. In your case, that would mean that `@model.get('coordinates')` would be `undefined` in the `v.render()` call above and you would get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
...
```

then, the `m.fetch()` gets its data from the server and [triggers a `"change"` event](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-fetch), that event would then call `render` on your view and you would get this:

```
[51.4528837, -0.9739059999999428]
51.4528837
-0.9739059999999428
done
```

That sequence of messages is exactly what you're seeing in your console.

I'd guess that you'r doing something like this (as above):

```
m = new M
m.fetch()
v = new V(model: m)
$(something).append(v.render().el)
```

Try checking to see if `@model` is actually loaded inside `render` and throw up some sort of "loading..." message if it isn't; then let the `"change"` event trigger the "real" rendering.

---

PS: You can use `@` instead of `this` in CoffeeScript:

```
initialize: ->
  @model.on('change', @render, @)
render: ->
  #...
  @
```

You could also use a [fat arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) to define your `render` method and not worry about supply a context to `@model.on`:

```
initialize: ->
  @model.on('change', @render)
render: =>
  #...
  @
```

Furthermore, if you're using a recent version of Backbone, you have a [`$el`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-%24el) in your view instances so you could:

```
render: =>
  @$el.html(...)
  #...
  @
```

Comment: This explanation makes sense. You're right about how my calls are structured so I edited my router to this:

  `place: (id) ->
    @model = new GD.Models.Place({id: "#{id}"})
    @model.fetch(
      success: (data) ->
        view = new GD.Views.Place(model: data)
        $('#container').html(view.render().el)
    )`

This works fine and the page is rendering.

Comment: What is still a myth to me is why the change in the model doesn't properly fire the render method and change the div contents.
Is it something to do with this line - 

        `$('#container').html(view.render().el)`

- giving an error in the router and therefore there are no contents there to refresh.
What is standard practice in handling things like this? Is there any?

Comment: @socratic_singh: The event is firing, that's why you were getting the second successful `render` call. The error was (probably) coming from calling `view.render()` before the `fetch` finished. My standard practice is to check that the model is renderable in `render` (or equivalently, in the template) and bind `render` to the `"change"` event, that way I don't have to worry about the timing.

Comment: Absolute legend, you're turning out to be my backbone tutor(!)

Comment: @socratic_singh: Thanks. You might want to read [Derick Bailey's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/93448/derick-bailey) blog too, he's pretty good at this stuff.